# Cron job not working in Whenever gem in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I have written this method in my model :-

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_message
    ShortMessage.create(message: "cron job")
    puts "created"
  end
end
```

And then I updated schedule.rb file :-

```
every 1.minute do
  runner "Message.create_message", :environment => "development"
end
```

And finally executed all this cammands :-

```
whenever --update-crontab
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON
```

But nothing is created in my database, when checked from console **ShortMessage.last**

Comment: What is `ShortMessage`? Any validations on the model? How does your log file look like?

Comment: No it is only table name i.e. short_messages.

Comment: Check if it's running by `crontab -l`

Comment: Please attach `crontab -l` and `which ruby` output

Comment: What is runner name for `Message` class? Is it `message.rb` ?

Comment: @zeitnot, Yes it is message.rb file

Comment: @dan-klasson, this is what I get when I run "tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON" cammand :-
    Feb 24 22:31:01 Sonu-pc CRON[23393]: (sonu) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd 
    /home/sonu/Desktop/voice_rules && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e 
    development '\''Message.create_message'\''')

Comment: And also when I run this cammand from terminal then it executed perfectly(means short_message is created in DB) :-
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/sonu/Desktop/voice_rules && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development '\''Message.create_message'\'''

Answer (score 1):

Cron does not initialise full session, if you're using ruby version manager like rvm - it may not get loaded, for using in cron you need ruby wrappers or load rvm, for more details look into [rvm documentation about cron](https://rvm.io/deployment/cron), command for cron will look like

```
cd (working-dir) && /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default/bundle bin/rails runner -e development '\''Message.create_message'\'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear existing cron jobs.

```
crontab -r
```

Update cronjob with the environment.

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
```